# changing the value of object in attrs inside controller of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive as follows

```
<div ng-controller=prdController as prd>   
<my-dir data=prd.data ng-click=stateChanged()></my-dir>
</div>
```

where prd.data is an object. In my directive I did the following

```
app.directive('myDir',function(){
    return {
        scope:{
            data:'=data'
        },
        templateUrl: './templates/testtemplate.html',
        controllerAs:'bd',
        controller:function($scope,$attrs){
            this.stateChanged = function (value) {
                $attrs.data = { 'fd','sdfs'};
            }
       }
     });
```

I am unable to modify the data value within the controller how do I proceed thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you use $scope.data to update the data attribute of directive

Comment: thanks never new i could access it through $scope

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in the way you trying to get `data` object in your controller.

You should try to get it by `$scope.data`. All directive inputs getting attached to your internal scope.

`$attrs` - is a hash object with key-value pairs of normalized attribute names and their corresponding attribute values. According to AngularJS docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("prdController", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = "krupesh";
  $scope.stateChanged = function() {
    $scope.data = "kotecha";
  }
});
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<div>{{data}}</div>"
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller=prdController as prd>
  <my-dir data="prd.data" ng-click=stateChanged()></my-dir>
</div>
```